# How to dynamicly set a array variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with this code:

```
$a['i'] = 1;

$b = '$a[\'i\']';
echo $$b;
```

It display an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: $a['i'] in test.php on line 6

Is it possible to create dynamic array variable?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: In my example I am trying to edit an multidimensional array. There is a problem when I try to add data to my array (JSON). I don't have fixed dimension of array, it my be 2 or more dimension (I am building a model for Web form, and I want to add invalid value to JSON).

Now in one of the methods of Web form object I have code which checks repopulation object to add invalid value if needed.

I can not just add a value to JSON array, I need to edit it on multidimensional level.

For now I came up on solution to dynamically generate variable name and, then, edit it. If someone have solution it will be appreciated.

```
private $form = array(
        'form_contact'=>array(
            'attr'=>array('tag'=>'FORM', 'method'=>'post'),

        'elem'=>array(

            'fs_contact'=>array(
                'attr'=>array('legend'=>'Kontakt', 'tag'=>'FSET'),
            'elem'=>array(

                'name'=>array(
                    'attr'=>array('SPAN'=>'Ime i prezime', 'title'=>'Unesite Vaše ime i prezime', 'tag'=>'INPUT', 'type'=>'text'),
                    'validat'=>array('req'=>'noscript', 'length'=>255),
                    'invalid'=>true), // Holds info that this is invalid
                'www'=>array(
                    'attr'=>array('SPAN'=>'Web sajt', 'title'=>'Unesite Vaš sajt', 'tag'=>'INPUT', 'type'=>'text'),
                    'validat'=>array('length'=>255)),
                'email'=>array(
                    'attr'=>array('SPAN'=>'E-mail', 'title'=>'Unesite Vaš email', 'tag'=>'INPUT', 'type'=>'text'),
                    'validat'=>array('req'=>'email', 'length'=>255)),
                'message'=>array(
                    'attr'=>array('SPAN'=>'Poruka', 'cols'=>'60', 'rows'=>'5', 'title'=>'Unesite Vašu poruku', 'tag'=>'TEXTA', 'value'=>'nesto'),
                    'validat'=>array('req'=>'all')),
                'submit_new_contact_form'=>array(
                    'attr'=>array('tag'=>'INPUT', 'type'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Pošalji poruku!'))
                ))// FS end
            )) // Form end      
        );// Array end
```

Comment: @mc10: That echos the string `$a['i']`.

Comment: You could use `eval($b);`, but the use of `eval()` is evil.

Comment: give more context of what you are really trying to solve (the multidimensional array + recursion you mentioned in a comment below)

Comment: `eval($b);` is giving error. Even this is not working `eval("\$c = \$\$b;");`

Comment: @mc10 Post your answer, eval("\$c = $b;"); is working. And lol for eval() is evil! :)

Comment: eval is still evil. There should be better solution, but you need to explain what you're trying to do better.

Comment: Its all about multidimensional array and keys that have another subarray. That target key and its array holds place for update operation (of another child subarray). That is why I can not use array_walk_recursive, because that function operate on end data (non array).

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of data you want to have? What should it be. I've done many unkown depth recursive arrays in php/etc. none of them ever required eval.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way, as PHP thinks you're looking for a variable with the name `$a['i']`, rather than the `'i'` key in the `$a` array.

The proper, and conventional, way is to use a dynamic key/index instead:

```
$b = 'i';
echo $a[$b];
```

Comment: In a object method I am trying to edit array. There is a problem with reference to that array, because that array is multidimensional and I am going recursively. Only solution that I got is to access it dynamically and add some data to the array. Any suggestions?